# Mysqli Select values and count all in one sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, count

I want to run this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as res,user_id FROM user WHERE HAVING res!=?
```

and I want to get count and user_id with array is that possible in one query?because if it is not I should do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as res FROM user WHERE HAVING res!=?
```

then check if it is success I need run below:

```
SELECT user_Id FROM user WHERE HAVING res!=?
```

Answer (score 1):

> and I want to get count and user_id with array is that possible in one query?

Rather, it makes no sense.

Once you have an array you can always have the count.

So just select your ids without count, store them in array, and then count that array. As simple as that

Comment: Ok I know I can store this and count but my problem is I dont want to select them each time I want to select them if count is not equal to current count